# BufferCount(2, 1) with first emission in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have an Observable:

```
1----2----3----3----2----1-|
```

I use

```
.bufferCount(2, 1)
```

and the output is

```
--[1,2]-[2,3]-[3,3]-[3,2]-[2,1]-|
```

then I chain

```
.filter(twoEmissions => twoEmissions[0] !== twoEmissions[1])
```

which makes:

```
 --[1,2]-[2,3]-------[3,2]-[2,1]-|
```

then I chain

```
.map(twoEmissions => twoEmissions[1])
```

to leave only latest emissions, so my final output is:

```
-----2-----3------------2----1---|
```

My problem is that first emission is ommited int this case.
I tried to use buffer() insted of bufferCount() with following closingNotifier:

```js
bufferClosingNotifier = sourceObservable$
  .scan((acc, val, index) => (index), 0)
  .filter((index: number) => index === 0 || index > 0 && index % 2 !== 0)
```

It emits 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th... emission but they are not overlapping.

How can I have bufferCount(2, 1) but emitting first emission of source observable anyway?

Comment: `.startWith(undefined).bufferCount(2, 1)`

Comment: thank you @cartant, that helped!

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is the following:

Given a stream of values:

```
1----2----3----3----2----1-|
```

I only want succeeding unique values so that the ending stream is

```
1----2----3---------2----1-|
```

You can use [`.distinctUntilChanged()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) to get this behaviour:

> #### [`public distinctUntilChanged(compare: function): Observable source`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged)
>
> Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source
>   Observable that are distinct by comparison from the previous item.
>
> If a comparator function is provided, then it will be called for each
>   item to test for whether or not that value should be emitted.
>
> If a comparator function is not provided, an equality check is used by
>   default.

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,3,2,1])
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: I oversimplified my question, my observable emits objects which are always different if not refer to same thing.

Comment: @JarosławRewers `distinctUntilChanged` takes a comparator function as parameter: `obs.distinctUntilChanged((a,b)=>_.isEqual(a,b))` (using lodash).

Comment: wasn't aware of that. Thank you, @n00dl3!